# AmpScript to creating a Dynamic URL for download files

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to creating a download link using AMPscript to construct a complete URL.

Eg: original url link: "[http://xxx.tempsite.Relatório/Mai19.pdf](http://xxx.tempsite.Relat%C3%B3rio/Mai19.pdf)"

Where "Mai19", I use AMPscript to populate dynamically using HREF

Eg: HREF=(URL/ampcript.pdf) "click here to download"

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [CONCAT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) and setting the link as a variable

```
%%[
set @PDFVariable = "Mai19.pdf"
set @link = CONCAT("http://xxx.tempsite.Relatório/", @PDFVariable)
]%%
```

You can further make it dynamic with [FormatDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm) or [DatePart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DatePart.htm) based on the date as I'm guessing you're trying to do with "Mai."

```
%%[ 
set @month = FormatDate(Now(),'MMMM')
set @year = FormatDate(Now(),'yy')
set @PDFVariable = CONCAT(@month, @year, ".pdf")
set @link = CONCAT("http://xxx.tempsite.Relatório/", @PDFVariable)
]%%
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%">click here to download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Jackson! I just made some changes but it worked perfectly!

Comment: Good to hear! Please select my answer as the accepted answer.